# How to create a partition of MySQL table for each distinct value of a column?

Tags: mysql, dynamic, distinct, partitioning

Suppose I have a table created by the following instruction:

```
CREATE TABLE `SensorsData` (
  `sensor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sensor_id`,`timestamp`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`sensor_id`) REFERENCES `Sensors` (`sensor_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Such a table will contain a lot of data and I want to create partitions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html).

I would like to have a partition for each distinct value of the column sensor_id.
I do not know in advance the number of distinct values of sensor_id, so the number of partitions should increase every time I create a new row into SensorsData with a new sensor_id.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839177/dynamic-mysql-partitioning-based-on-unixtime) solution using REORGANIZE PARTITION seems to be close to what I have to do, but I'm not sure how to rearrange it in order to make it works for my scenario. Could you help me with it or suggest different approaches?

Comment: Are you sure you want DOUBLE?

Comment: Yes, in my real scenario I have many double fields. Why?

Comment: Because DOUBLE implies that the exact value stored is unimportant - which may or may not be the case (but it usually *is* important).

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand the point. My problem is related to how to create partitions over the value of sensor_id. The field `data` has been added just to give an idea of the scenario.

Comment: Show us the main queries that will hit the table.  It may be that `PARTITIONing` will provide nothing useful for you.  [_Further discussion_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/)

Comment: Principally I need to select all (or a subset of) the rows contained into each partition. In other words, I want to know all data collected by a sensor or data collected by a sensor in a specific period.